# wild card in if statement in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using a windows bactchfile to grab all folders that don't start with "abc".  Therefore, ignoring folders names abcd, and abc123, etc.  It seems the IF statement does not process wild cards.  How can I go about doing this.

```
for /D %%A in (*) do ( 
    if not %%A == abc* (Do commands)
)
```

I found some help saying to use something like the following but am unable to get the correct syntax.

```
%variable:~offset,length%
```

I tried this syntax but its not correct:

```
if not %%A:~0:3 == abc (Do commands)
```

Comment: why don't you `for /D %%A in (abc*) do ...`?

Comment: Substrings can only be used on environmental variables. Can't use them with the `FOR` variables.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /AD * ^|findstr /vi "^abc" ') do (commands)`

Answer (score 2):

just to give an alternative without using a temporary variable (and therefore no need for [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)):

```
for %%a in (*) do (
   echo %%a|findstr /ib "abc" || (
     echo Do commands with '%%a'
   )
)
```

`findstr /ib` looks for strings that start (`b`) with a certain substring (`abc`), ignoring capitalization (`i`)
`||` works as "if previous command (findstr) failed then"

Comment: To have folders that **don't** start with `abc` you should use findstr  `/v` switch.

Comment: @LotPings thanks, I missed the `not`. Edited (but used a different approach)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b * ^| findstr /vbi abc') do (
  REM your commands processing file %%F here
)
```

The `eol=:` is probably not necessary. I include it because you do not want to exclude any files that begin with the EOL character, which defaults to `;`, and it is possible for a file name to begin with `;`. No file can begin with `:`, so that is safe for EOL.

I opted to use FOR /F because that caches the entire list of files before the loop executes any command, leaving you free to do anything to those files, including renaming them.

If you use a simple FOR loop, then it is possible that a renamed file would get processed twice (or more!) because FOR can begin processing files before it has finished discovering them. The new name of a renamed file could show up later in the list and get reprocessed.